# Why do add(); is always written in constructor while adding button to frame

Tags: java, button, addition, frame

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class but extends Frame {
    but() {
        Button b = new Button("OK");
        add(b);
        b.addActionListener(new MyAn_innerclass());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        but obj = new but();
        obj.setSize(200, 100);
        obj.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyAn_innerclass implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

i have this code and i wonder why do we write this add(b); in constructor of the button class while adding button to the frame.I know that add(b); is used to push button to the frame but why write it in constructor,also if i remove the constructor the add function is not recognized by the compiler.why is it so?
Sorry if it sounds lame but i am a beginner to java

Comment: you are asking about `add(b);` or `new Button("OK");` ?!!

Answer (score 0):

because when you creating swing frames you need to add components as soon as you start frame .when you create new instance of a class ,constructor get called .adding component is good to do in constructor .but you can also make a method and call it from constructor instead putting add in constructor but both are same ..

```
public class but extends Frame
{
  but(){
     Button b= new Button("OK");//add component immediately to frame 
     add(b);
  }
}
```

if you didn't add in the constructor you will see empty frame until you add components  to it.

you can also add component in another method but you have to call it from constructor

```
public class but extends Frame
{
  but(){
    initcomponent();//call component creating and adding method 
  }
  public void initcomponent(){
    Button b= new Button("OK");//add component immediately to frame 
    add(b);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you asking about Button class itself (i.e `Button b = new Button("OK");`), then "OK" is the label of the button and you DON'T have to add it to the button while creating it. You can create the button then add the label after that:

```
 Button b = new Button();
 b.setLabel("OK");
```

---

If you asking about `add(b);`, at first it's a method not a constructor, then it's pretty logical to enforce you to add an argument to it, as you are adding some component to the frame, so what's that component? an empty one? it must be some component(Button, Text, ...etc).